# Error: Migration is required due to the following errors in React native (Realm)

Tags: react-native, npm, realm, apk, database-migration

We are getting error like for following while APK file installation for particular OS version ( 8.0) in Android.
But, This is working fine while development.

Error is following

```
Error: Migration is required due to the following errors:

ReactNativeJS: - Property 'Some Field' has been added.
ReactNativeJS: - Property 'other Field' has been added.
```

We are using Realm DB in our React Native project.
As per some forums suggestions, We have deleted node modules and reset cache, Delete nodemodules/realm too. And done npm install too.

But, Still same error showing while trying to install APK, But, This issue not happening while we run in development mode.

> Note: This issue happening only particular devices (OS version 8.0), Other devices its
>   working fine.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

I know that is late but for anyone who comes for this here the answer:
Realm requires for any update made to its schema to be solved using something called a Migration. This was invented having in considering that when you update your app from an version to another it might have some changes to the database that may make you data inconsistent.
The easiest way the get rid of this is deleting all the current database data if you change your schema add   `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` add configurations as below

`Realm.open({ schema: [BookSchema], deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded: true, })`

The other way is buy creating a migration your self as described  at the  [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest#migrations)

Answer (score 0):

Restrictions on use of non-SDK interfaces

To help ensure app stability and compatiblity, the platform restricts the use of some non-SDK methods and fields; these restrictions apply whether you attempt to access these methods and fields directly, via reflection, or using JNI. In Android 9, your app can continue to access these restricted interfaces; the platform uses toasts and log entries to bring them to your attention. If your app shows such a toast, it is important that you pursue an implementation strategy other than the restricted interface. If you feel that no alternative strategy is feasible, you may file a bug to request reconsideration of the restriction.

Restrictions on Non-SDK Interfaces contains further important information. You should review it to ensure that your app continues to function properly.

Starting in Android 9 (API level 28), the platform restricts which non-SDK interfaces your app can use. These restrictions apply whenever an app references a non-SDK interface or attempts to obtain its handle using reflection or JNI. These restrictions were put in place to help improve the user and developer experience and reduce the risks of crashes for users and emergency rollouts for developers. For more information about this decision, see [Improving Stability by Reducing Usage of non-SDK Interfaces.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/improving-stability-by-reducing-usage.html)

See [here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces?hl=en) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the schema version when you add or remove a property

```html
const config = {
  schema: [Person],
  // increment the 'schemaVersion', since 'age' has been added to the schema
  schemaVersion: 2,
  deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded // use this for development only to delete the database when a schema mismatch requires a migration
};
```

Read here for more info https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/realm-database/change-an-object-model/

Answer (score 0):

## My example of code with Realm migration

```
export async function openRealm() {
  return open({
    path: join(DB_PATH, 'realm', 'task'),
    schema: [
      TaskSchema,
    ],
```

### Increase version of schema

```
    schemaVersion: 2, // 1 -> 2
```

### Add logic to migration

```
    onMigration: (oldRealm, newRealm) => {
      if (oldRealm.schemaVersion == 1 && newRealm.schemaVersion == 2) {
        const newObjects: Results<TaskDto & Realm.Object> =
          newRealm.objects('Task');
        const oldObjects: Results<TaskDto & Realm.Object> =
          newRealm.objects('Task');

        for (const objectIndex in newObjects) {
          const oldObject = oldObjects[objectIndex];
          const newObject = newObjects[objectIndex];

          for (const key in oldObject.keys()) {
            newObject[key] = oldObject[key];
          }
```

### In my case I added new field `assigned`

```
          newObject.assigned = '';
        }
      }
    },
  });
}
```